# Console Error in steal.js: "Cannot define property _instanceDefinitions"

Tags: node.js, stealjs, donejs

Loading a page produces the following error:

`steal.js:140 Potentially unhandled rejection [1] TypeError: Cannot define property _instanceDefinitions, object is not extensible
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.defineExpando (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/can-define/define-helpers/define-helpers.js:20:11)
    at DefineMap.setKeyValue (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/can-define/map/map.js:52:30)
    at Object.setKeyValue (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/can-reflect/reflections/get-set/get-set.js:50:23)
    at Object.eval (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/can-reflect/reflections/shape/shape.js:701:23)
    at String.eval (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/can-reflect/reflections/shape/shape.js:445:21)
    at Object.eachListLike (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/can-reflect/reflections/shape/shape.js:376:17)
    at Object.eachIndex (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/can-reflect/reflections/shape/shape.js:338:16)
    at Object.eachKey (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/can-reflect/reflections/shape/shape.js:443:16)
    at Object.assignDeepMap (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/can-reflect/reflections/shape/shape.js:698:8)`

Hot realoding does not work anymore. This seems to come from steal.js and i have no idea how this is related to my code.
Could it be that this problem is happening in a worker thread...?

Here my package.json:

`...
"dependencies": {
    "can-ajax": "^1.1.4",
    "can-component": "^3.3.10",
    "can-connect": "^1.5.9",
    "can-define": "^1.5.5",
    "can-route": "^3.2.3",
    "can-route-pushstate": "^3.1.2",
    "can-set": "^1.3.2",
    "can-stache": "^3.11.1",
    "can-view-autorender": "^3.1.1",
    "can-zone": "^0.6.13",
    "done-autorender": "^1.4.0",
    "done-component": "^1.0.0",
    "done-css": "^3.0.1",
    "done-serve": "^1.5.0",
    "generator-donejs": "^1.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "steal": "^1.5.15",
    "steal-less": "^1.2.0",
    "steal-stache": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "can-fixture": "^1.1.1",
    "donejs-cli": "^1.0.0",
    "funcunit": "^3.2.0",
    "steal-qunit": "^1.0.1",
    "steal-tools": "^1.9.1",
    "testee": "^0.3.0"
  }
...`

Node:

`node --version
v8.9.2
npm --version
5.5.1`

OS:

`ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]`

Comment: The problem is that something is trying to set a property on a sealed object. This is difficult to debug without seeing your code. Is there a way you could share your code?

Comment: Hi Ryan, here the code: https://github.com/indianscout/app THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a short term solution, try adding `{ seal: false }` to your app viewmodel:

```
const AppViewModel = DefineMap.extend({ seal: false }, {
    title: {
        value: 'spotwizard.org',
        serialize: false
    }
});
```

**Update:** after further testing, you are trying to set the "page" property on your app viewmodel, but you did not define one. Your app viewmodel should look like this:

```
const AppViewModel = DefineMap.extend({
    title: {
        value: 'spotwizard.org',
        serialize: false
    },
    page: 'string'
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, the route prop itself... I did not realize that. Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: And just so you know, the error you reported has been fixed in later versions of `can-define`: https://github.com/canjs/can-define/issues/309

Comment: Yes, good to know. I actually did not know where the problem is coming from. I was searching through the stealjs issues but did not find anything similar. THX for helping. Regards